# How to simulate the error [IBM] [CLI Driver] [DB2/AIX64] SQL0911N in integration bus?

Tags: db2, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

In my ESQL code I'm getting a sql exception:

```
SQL0911N  The current 
transaction has been rolled back because of a deadlock or timeout.  Reason code "68".SQLSTATE=40001
```

I need to simulate this situation to understand where the error is coming from.

Can anyone help me generate this exception in the IBM Integration Bus ESQL code?

Comment: It is If your aim is to understand the cause of this exception, talk with your DBA who should be able to tell you exactly which statement(s) and which table(s) and which row(s) are involved.   You can then take locks on that table to cause the symptom to recreate.   Involve your DBA.

Comment: I already know which table and rows are in question, however I don't know how to simulate it.

Comment: Simulation is the wrong approach. Better to trigger the real exception. Just use SQL (dynamic) to select the rows for update and do not commit (this will lock the rows and keep them locked until you rollback), and then run your program. A DBA will quickly be able to suggest the changes needed to avoid the lock conflict.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: You don't know how to write a DELETE statement, or UPDATE statement ? Or you don't know how to disable autocommit on your connection? Google these for your toolset.

Comment: I don't know how to disable autocommit in my connection.

Comment: this depends on the tool you are using, hence my suggestion for you to use google, as it is a FAQ.   For the shell command line (bash/db2cmd.exe etc) use "db2 +c update...".   For GUI tools like dbvis, squirrelsql etc there are settings in the application to do this.